# Updating ArcMap Statusbar from AddIn?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, add-in

I'm using this statement in an add in to update the first pane of the ArcMap 10 statusbar:

`ArcMap.Application.StatusBar.set_Message(0, message);`

When the method is called, no exceptions are raised.  In my OnClick method, I display a message box and when that occurs, I do see the text of the last message.  It seems like the pane needs to be refreshed, but I don't see a method that does that.

I tried:

```
 ArcMap.Application.RefreshWindow();
```

but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding a [Application.DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx), the STA thread probably don't have time to consume events. An other way would be to create a background worker thread that does your work, that would free the STA thread to process the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am using StatusBar messages to inform the user of progress during a long piece of processing. My messages were not being displayed, except if a message box was also created.

The suggestion of MathiasWestin works well. Tested Arc10.3.1 Desktop with VB.Net
The code is of the form
            My.ArcMap.Application.StatusBar.Message(0) = EditorMessage
            Application.DoEvents()

Note that the ArcMap application and the Application are different.
I also tried using  system.threading.thread.sleep to add a 100msec delay. This did not work, longer times would then become noticible by users.

Using Application.DoEvents also seems to help when changing mouse cursors.
The  ESRI.FrameWork.MouseCursor mouse cursor is defined:
        Dim pMouseCursor As MouseCursor = New MouseCursor   '

I have found that the mouse cursor reverts to the standard pointer after geoprocessing jobs. Setting it again to a wait cursor using:
            pMouseCursor.SetCursor(2) ' 2 is wait cursor
sometimes did not work.
Adding a DoEvents made the switching of the mouse cursor more reliable.

Answer (score -1):

Untested suggestion:  instead of passing 0, try ArcMap.Application.hWnd.

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work and you are likely to get an ArgumentException (does not fall within expected range).

Comment: The value 0 is the integer value of the esriStatusBarPanes.esriStatusMain  enum value which is the "Leftmost pane where application messages are displayed."